# How to address WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

So the problems have been asked a couple of times here, I've tried multiple solutions none of which worked. So, I am trying to automate the process of signing in to google. But google always throws in "Couldn’t sign you in" after you enter your email, also it presented me with "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software". However, I tried using proxies and such methods to solve the problem, and I've tried different solutions but none is working as I am faced with that error ( in the title), I am guessing that I have setup my proxy incorrectly.Here's my code:

This code is just supposed to connect to a proxy and avoid google automation detection only, and start at https://google.com

```
try:

    import sys
    import os

    from fp.fp import FreeProxy
    from fake_useragent import UserAgent
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
    import time
except Exception as e:

    print("Error ->>>: {} ".format(e))
    
class Spoofer(object):

    def __init__(self, country_id=['US'], rand=True, anonym=True):
        self.country_id = country_id
        self.rand = rand
        self.anonym = anonym
        self.userAgent, self.ip = self.get()

    def get(self):
        ua = UserAgent()
        proxy = FreeProxy(country_id=self.country_id, rand=self.rand, anonym=self.anonym).get()
        ip = proxy.split("://")[1]
        print(ip)
        return ua.random, ip
    
class DriverOptions(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.options = Options()
        self.options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        self.options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
#         self.options.add_argument('--start-fullscreen')
        self.options.add_argument('--single-process')
        self.options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        self.options.add_argument("--incognito")
        self.options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
        self.options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
        self.options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
        self.options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        self.options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
        

        self.helperSpoofer = Spoofer()

        self.options.add_argument('user-agent={}'.format(self.helperSpoofer.userAgent))
        self.options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % self.helperSpoofer.ip)
        
class WebDriver(DriverOptions):

    def __init__(self, path=''):
        DriverOptions.__init__(self)
        self.driver_instance = self.get_driver()

    def get_driver(self):

        print("""
        IP:{}
        UserAgent: {}
        """.format(self.helperSpoofer.ip, self.helperSpoofer.userAgent))

        PROXY = self.helperSpoofer.ip
        webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
            "httpProxy":PROXY,
            "ftpProxy":PROXY,
            "sslProxy":PROXY,
            "noProxy":None,
            "proxyType":"MANUAL",
            "autodetect":False
        }
        webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['acceptSslCerts'] = True

#         path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), )

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'./chromedriver.exe', options=self.options)
        driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
        driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
            "source":
                "const newProto = navigator.__proto__;"
                "delete newProto.webdriver;"
                "navigator.__proto__ = newProto;"
        })

        return driver
    
def main():

    driver= WebDriver(path='./chromedriver.exe')
    driverinstance = driver.driver_instance
    driverinstance.get("https://google.com")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("done")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried different methods, listed in other stackoverflow answers with the same error, but none are working.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

[image: err_tunnel_connection_failed]

...implies proxy exception occured and Chrome can't go online due to incorrect proxy settings.

It typically occurs in [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) when the web browser refuses to establish an Internet connection through the proxy due to incorrect proxy settings.

---

### Details

When connecting to the Internet over a virtual private network (VPN) or proxy server the header information from user requests is removed/altered to access the websites which helps to conceal your identity online. In majority of the cases, this will not result in any issues and you will be able to maintain a connection to websites without any complications. However there are instances in which there might be a disparity between the data that was expected and the data that was supplied which leads to the **ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED** using the Chrome browser.

---

### Solution

A few areas to check can be:

- Verify that the proxy settings are proper.
- Update Chrome/ChromeDriver to the latest version.
- Clear browsing data and cache.
- Delete the *`Cookies and other site data`* and *`Cached images and files`*.
- Remove Conflicting Browser Extensions.
- Reset Google Chrome Browser.
- Reset Internet settings from cmd (*Windows*):

  ```
  ipconfig /flushdns
  ipconfig /registerdns
  ipconfig /release
  ipconfig /renew
  NETSH winsock reset catalog
  NETSH int ipv4 reset reset.log
  NETSH int ipv6 reset reset.log
  ```

---

### Alternative

As an alternative you can opt to use [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) or [opera](/questions/tagged/opera) browser.